# Use the useRef Hook for Component-Specific

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend, antd

I'm using useRef to auto-focus an Antd TextArea component. On the same page, I have another TextArea as well. I need the ref for the first component only, but it is also being applied to the second component. How can I handle this scenario?

This is my first component:

```
            <TextArea
              ref={inputRef}
              id="message"
              style={{
                borderRadius: 5,
                border: "1px solid #D9D9D9",
                backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
              }}
              size={5}
            />
```

This is my second component:

```
       <Input
         prefix={<SearchOutlined />}
         placeholder="Search notes"
         style={{
           borderRadius: "5px",
        }}
     
      />
```

I'm using useEffect to set focus:

```
   // Focus on input field
      useEffect(() => {
       if (inputRef.current) {
        inputRef.current.focus();
       }
      }, [inputRef.current]);
```

I want to set the ref for the first component only. Is there any way to specifically set focus to a particular component?

Comment: I think your problem is related to `useEffect`. You should remove `inputRef.current` from it's dependency array supposing that you want to focus on first input only on initial component render (wich I think to be the right behavior)